# writing float to a 4 byte register

Tags: floating-point, cpu-registers

I have a floating point number and need to store this in a 4 byte register.
However when I do the operation as below example, I donot get a correct value as it is corrupted as 0x0000C000.

```
typedef float FLT;
FLT val , temp_val;
val = -6.513467;
(volatile FLT*)0x402174 = val;
```

Instead, if I use an addressed variable as below and check at &_temp_val, it works.

```
temp_val = val;
```

Value at _temp_val is 0xC0D06E52(IEEE 754 format)

I am unable to understand why I am unable to write into the register.

Answer (score 0):

You should access that register via one of the variables from your platform definition headers rather than hard-coded via its address.

Your C compiler might use that register as well under the hood, thus your assignment might get clobbered.

You can check this by having a look at the assembly code your C compiler generates for your code.

Your C compiler might allow for a syntax like this as well.

```
register float *f asm ("r0") = ...;
```